# Is the phrase "voler la victoire" followed by the preposition "à" or "de"?

Tags: expressions, usage, prépositions

> Prends garde. Je suis bien décidé à **te voler la victoire** !

When I say this, for instance, I have the structure "voler quelque chose **à** quelqu'un" in mind. But I just stumbled across a webpage where a native French speaker used "voler la victoire **de** quelqu'un" instead. Which is the correct preposition to use?

Answer (score 3):

Both are used. The preposition depends on whether it is the *victoire de quelqu'un* which is stolen, or if the *victoire* is stolen *à quelqu'un*.

> *J'ai volé la victoire **à** Jean* (C'est **à Jean** que j'ai volé la victoire)
>
> *J'ai volé la victoire **de** Jean* (C'est la victoire **de Jean** que j'ai volée)

The second might be due to hypercorrection to avoid *la victoire à quelqu'un*.

The first one seems much more idiomatic to me and is built like:

> *Voler la vedette **à** quelqu'un* (never: <s>Voler la vedette de quelqu'un</s>)

Comment: Le deuxième me donne l'impression que Jean a déjà gagné, et que c'est après coup que la victoire a été volée. Si c'est la victoire **de** Jean, il a déjà gagné. Du coup, c'est un peu bizarre.

Comment: Où alors c'était absolument sûr qu'il allait gagner. Dans le premier, c'est un éventualité, Jean **veut** gagner mais je lui ai volé **la** victoire, dans le second Jean **devait** gagner, mais je lui ai volé **sa** victoire. Qu'est-ce que t'en penses ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Il me semble que dans les deux cas la victoire revenait à Jean, mais dans le deuxième il y a tricherie après coup.